# Continuous moving graph in android

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I have developed a application which works like [ECG Graph](http://osama-oransa.blogspot.com/2010/03/draw-ecg-using-java-script-draw.html)

I have developed this using canvas and path.

Once the plotting of lines are completed in my screen, it will start again from the 0 position. But the problem is that it gets starting overlapped.

So how can i clear that particular position?

Comment: Are you saying that your graph draws from the left side of the screen to the right side of the screen, and when it reaches the right, it begins drawing on the left side again?  And that it now draws over what you originally drew there, but you'd like to clear the previous drawing?

Or are you trying to scroll your graph once it hits the right side, so the left side gradually slides off-screen?

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do?
But screen does not slides.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the canvas with

```
mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);  //or whatever colour is appropriate.
```

I am trying to do something like you are saying but with a moving graph off to the left and am achieving it with

```
mPath.offset(-x, 0);
```